# How do I retrieve number of users connected on IIS at any point?

Tags: .net, session

I want to know how many users are connected to the IIS web server at any point on a simple .net page. Is there a way using a native .net class in 3.5 that will tell me this information? I want to create a simple web page that will give me the total number of users/open sessions at a given time.

Currently, I am using Perfmon to get this information however I want to create a simple webpage to retrieve this info

Appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance.

Niraj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update 1:** To be more simple ( and accurate ), Just use the PerformanceCounter object to get the information I specified below.

**Update 0:** There is a [msdn artical about how to show performance counter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms979194.aspx) in asp.net page ( and more, but that is not important).

You can show the

> web service => current connections => total

counter on your page.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running IIS7, I know that [Microsoft.Web.Administration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.aspx) let's you pull a list of requests for a given worker process. Sadly I've only ran it in our admin scripts so I'm not sure how it'll behave in a web process or what the security requirements are, but it might help you out.